# How to override an agent in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

My goal is to create a pipeline, where every stage is having the same agent, except of 1 stage (Stage E in the example below)

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile.tester'
            args '-v $HOME/.docker:/root/.docker'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('A') { ... }
        stage('B') { ... }
        stage('C') { ... }
        stage('D') { ... }
        stage('E') {
            agent {
                dockerfile {
                    filename 'Dockerfile.deploy'
                    args '-v $HOME/.docker:/root/.docker'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('F') { ... }
    }
}
```

What I can do so far is to set globally the agent to none and then set the  agent `Dockerfile.tester` for each stage and for the 1 other stage I set it to `Dockerfile.deploy`. Any idea how I can set it globally once and then just override it?

Here the new error from if I do it like above:

```
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10

Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

 > git config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/*********/*********.git # timeout=10

Cleaning workspace

 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10

Resetting working tree

 > git reset --hard # timeout=10

 > git clean -fdx # timeout=10

Fetching without tags

Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/*********/*********.git

 > git --version # timeout=10

using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials BitBucket Login for checkout / pushing

 > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/*********/********.git +refs/heads/dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev

Checking out Revision ab0d4a522d872a129f53a74f6ecadafb8fd82f11 (dev)

 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10

 > git checkout -f ab0d4a522d872a129f53a74f6ecadafb8fd82f11

Commit message: "chore: test"

Cleaning workspace

 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10

Resetting working tree

 > git reset --hard # timeout=10

 > git clean -fdx # timeout=10

[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result

docker login failed
```

Comment: Isn't stage E running on the docker container built from `Dockerfile.deploy` ? Is that the issue here ?

Comment: yes stage E should use Dockerfile.deploy, but the problem is that if I make it like in the example above, then I get an error in the checkout step (see updated question above)

Comment: Checkout step is in stage E ? If yes, can you post what exactly you are doing in that stage ?

Comment: checkout is happening in E, but I am modifying the version before. Step E is a deployment step and in step D I am adding a git commit with a version update

Comment: Can you clarify, it works with agent none and explicit set of agent inside each stage, your question is if its possible to just override an agent set in outer scope with an agent declaration in some inner scope?

Comment: I've had a similar question and experience. It seems like if you specify it at the Pipeline scope and at a stage scope, the stage scope first tries to do a docker login that fails. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't state that you can't do it. It talks about the difference between a top level and stage level, but doesn't specify that you can't use both.